# Output a CDATA Literal node in XSL

Tags: xslt-1.0

I would like to output a node who has inside cdata info, how to achieve it?

I have

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="conditionExpression" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT}%2) == 0]]></conditionExpression>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<conditionExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT}%2) == 0]]></conditionExpression>
```

I get

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<conditionExpression>($V{REPORT_COUNT}%2) == 0</conditionExpression>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I tested it with 'xsltproc' and I couldn't replicate your error. Output is `<conditionExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT}%2) == 0]]></conditionExpression>` as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem either.

In any case, the correct way to generate the output you want is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="conditionExpression" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <conditionExpression>($V{REPORT_COUNT}%2) == 0</conditionExpression>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is no reason to add your own CDATA markup after you have told your processor to do it for you.

Comment: I'm using stylus studio to do this. I'll try another program, Thank you